# Why doesn't the atmosphere separate according to density?

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, density, air

Why don't dense gas elements sink to the ground and dense gas elements drift to the sky? Why don't we have layers of oxygen, nitrogen, carbon dioxide, etc.

Comment: Duplicate question (with answers) on Chemistry SE: [Why don't heavy and light gases separate in the atmosphere?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/61140)

Comment: Related question on Physics SE: [Why does air remain a mixture?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34733/179151)

Comment: work out $e^{-mgh/kT}$ for various $m$ values.